# Tcpdump Excluding Packet Attributes with "IP0"

Tags: c, networking, ip, tcpdump

I'm currently working on a project that constructs raw packets out of network flow level data. Unfortunately, when I send my packets over the localhost networking interface, I receive something like the following:

> 16:31:03.000624 00:01:02:03:04:05 > 00:09:08:07:06:05, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: IP0

Whereas a normal tcpdump recorded packet would look like:

> 16:31:03.000624 00:01:02:03:04:05 > 00:09:08:07:06:05, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: 172.217.14.238 > 10.0.0.204: ICMP echo reply, id 19577, seq 1, length 64

My question is, what would cause the rest of the information tied to the packet to be replaced by this "IP0"?

I've followed networking byte order to the best of my ability, using htons and htonl when required of me and inetaddr() as well.

Comment: Use `tcpdump -xx` to see the packet contents in hexadecimal, then see what is different between your packets and other packets.

Comment: Sounds like you put 0 for protocol.